# widget development

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, security, architecture

i develop a asp.net mvc3 shop application which is multi tenant. Each customer (around 1000 sites) has a own website where he likes to embed this solution. I use a extended validation SSL as this increases customer thrust.

so far i use iframes, which is not a good choice as on the payment step the customer does not see that the connection is SSL encrypted. so i choosed to put the page complete behind ssl and the page of the customer is ssl too. this is a unsatisfying approach, as i have problems with scrollbars, positioning of lightboxes etc.

my new approach would use asp.net mvc3 to provide controllers which deliver json results; on the client side i want to use a jquery based mvc framework together with jquery templates.

my question is, how should i handle SSL to let the customer see the traffic is encrypted? I want to avoid that customers need to create a proxy and route the traffic through their ssl certificate as many different CMS systems are involved so i can't provide a simple "how-to" to the customer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are accepting payment information, I recommend the entire site the user is interacting with be clearly running SSL.  So for your widget, I think it should navigate away to a pure SSL payment gateway.

Comment: Lets say it is a flight related problem, i need the credit card as form of authorisation. depending on what type of flight it is, i redirect it to another provider to take care he is responsible for the credit card disagio, some types i process myself.

Comment: Anytime you are taking a credit/debit card or any sensitive information, it needs to be over SSL.  Look up a Firefox plug-in called FireSheep and you will understand why.

Comment: Yes i know. Maybe i need to rephrase my question. Do i have to use a popup to make my widget working, or is it the problem of the clients CMS to show SSL and i make my JSON calls completely through SSL? Do i need to worry about same origin policy etc?